# Changing the tick labels in a BarLegend

Tags: legending, ticks

In the following plot, the colors mean the phase, so I need to label the color bar not in integers, but in increments of $\pi$. I searched, but could not find how to change the ticks. Does anyone have an idea?

```
ListDensityPlot[
    Table[ArcTan[Cos[x + y], Sin[x + y]], {x, 0, 10, 0.01}, {y, 0, 1.2, 0.01}], 
    DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

I consider myself an amateur. I was also interested in this question, and I found the following code solves the problem. However, the command that solves the problem ("Ticks") shows up highlighted in red. You can change many of the features of the legend, like size, add a label, etc.

```
Legended[
  ListDensityPlot[Table[ArcTan[Cos[x + y], Sin[x + y]], 
    {x, 0, 10, 0.01}, {y, 0, 1.2, 0.01}], 
    DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}}, 
    ColorFunction -> Hue
   ],
  BarLegend[
    {Hue, {-Pi, Pi}},
    Ticks -> Table[i, {i, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}],
    LegendMarkerSize -> 300
   ]
 ]
```

> [image: Plot]   [image: Ticks]

Comment: It seems `Ticks` is not an option for `BarLegend`, or at least in Mathematica 12.1.

Comment: This does not work in Mathematica 12.3. Although v12.3 seems to support `Ticks`,  `NumberForm::iprf` appears when one tries to use `Symbol` as the labels. Instead, we can cast the symbols into String, by `ToString@TraditionalForm@`.  Considering other changes, `BarLegend[{Hue, {-1, 1}}, 
 Ticks -> (Table[{i, ToString@TraditionalForm[i*Pi/4]}, {i, -1, 1, 1/4}])]` works in v12.3 for example.

Answer (score 8):

I wonder whether you would be content with a simpler `SwatchLegend`:

```
ListDensityPlot[
 Table[{2 Pi Sin[x], 2 Pi Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow",
 ImageSize -> 500,
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[
   Table[
    Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow}, Rescale[x, {0, 2 Pi}]], 
     {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}], 
   Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/8],
   LegendMarkers -> Graphics[Rectangle[]],
   LegendMarkerSize -> 15,
   LegendLayout -> (Grid[Reverse[#]] &)]]
```

[image: listdensityplot]

Comment: Thanks! A bit closer to what I want, however I am still curious if it is really possible to label the a bar legend with the increments of Pi.

Comment: @ceren I'm interested to know whether it's possible -I couldn't manage it but perhaps there is a more devious way waiting to be discovered...

Answer (score 5):

First, I'm not certain if your plot is correct. Notice that ListDensityPlot arranges successive rows of the array up the page, and successive columns across. The first iterator in the table creates the rows and the second iterator creates the columns. So if you want the normal x and y axis you have to reverse the iterators. On the other hand, DataRange coincides with what we normally call the x and y axis. The WRI examples are poor because they seem to all be symmetrical and thus don't illustrate this important issue. Here is a case where all the variation occurs in the x direction.

```
arrayTest = Table[x/10, {y, 0, 1.2, 0.01}, {x, 1, 10, 0.01}];
ListDensityPlot[arrayTest,
  DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}},
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  ColorFunction -> Hue,
  ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

I think that is what is intended. If I'm wrong about this please correct me.

In the sample plot, I would say: why have a legend at all? Why not just draw the constant ArcTan values on the plot and label them. In the following I use Tooltips, and also special labeling along the top x axis. (It would have been easier to reverse the top and bottom.) I also used pastel colors so the constant ArcTan lines would better show. Here is the plot using Show. (I have corrected the following so that it is entirely in regular Mathematica.)

```
array = Table[
   ArcTan[Cos[x + y], Sin[x + y]], {y, 0, 1.2, 0.01}, {x, 0, 10, 
    0.01}];

xticks = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {Table[
     1/5 (-6 + 5 k \[Pi]), {k, 1, 3}], {-\[Pi], 0, \[Pi]}}];

Show[
 {ListDensityPlot[array, DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}},
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Pastel"])],
  Table[Plot[
    Tooltip[ \[Pi] k - x , Mod[k \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], -\[Pi]]], {x, 0, 10},
     PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}], {k, 0, 3, 1/2}]},
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, xticks}},
 ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

Comment: What is `Draw` supposed to be? The code generates an error because it's not a graphics primitive.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I should have used Plot and taken it out of Graphics. (I developed it with Presentations and then converted to normal Mathematica and forgot about the Draw.)

Comment: As per your comment re `ListDensityPlot` and the way the matrices are plotted I agree that it's an important issue and also very frustrating. At the same time it's not consistent with functions like `ArrayPlot` that have the expected behaviour. Have you got any idea why this is so?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I am actually working on is not this function at all. This is only an example code to tell about my problem. Since the color distribution is quite random in my original research, labelling them on the axis with the increments of Pi will not look explanatory, I assume. That is why I need a color bar which shows ticks in increments of Pi.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the information on the listdensityplot function.

Comment: You might also consider using a contour plot, which might be faster. In any case another technique is to make TWO plots and place them on a "sheet of paper". One would be your data plot and the other would be a thin vertical density (or contour) plot with gradation in the vertical direction. You could control the tick labeling. Then set them both on the piece of paper using Inset. Probably simpler than trying to jigger the Legend code. I usually do this with primitives using Presentations so I don't think I'll work on an example now in regular Mathematica.

Comment: I liked this idea, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Files/BarLegend.en/I_70.gif
The code in the link as well as documentation of [BarLegend](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarLegend.html) may be helpful in customising bar legend. Look at Contours option.

I was overly optimistic, however,

```
ListDensityPlot[
 Table[ArcTan[Cos[x + y], Sin[x + y]], {x, 0, 10, 0.01}, {y, 0, 1.2, 
   0.01}], DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, {-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 250, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &), 
    LegendLabel -> "z-value"], {After, Top}], ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

is partially successful. The ticks for -1, 1 are not displayed. The LabelStyle option does not work but perhaps this is a start.

[image]

**EDIT**

```
Manipulate[
 ListDensityPlot[
  Table[ArcTan[Cos[x + y], Sin[x + y]], {x, 0, 10, 0.01}, {y, 0, 1.2, 
    0.01}], DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.2}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, p, LegendMarkerSize -> 250], Bottom], 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Hue], {p, {{-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}, {-1, 0, 
    1}, {-0.3, 0, 0.7}}}]
```

The above runs slowly on my old machine. However, illustrates the capacity to change tick labels with the caveat that sometimes not all specified contours are given a tick label.
Further `Dynamic@p` does not work as a way to speed up processing. Note {-Pi/2,Pi/2} is presented at 3 decimal places.

[image]

An example snapshot follows.

Comment: In my experiments, i found that the legend always ended up with de-rationalized numbers...

Comment: I don't see you using `LabelStyle`, could you elaborate on it not working, please?

Comment: In BarLegend  documentation LabelStyle appears as an option. However, it is not recognised when put in the code above. So I did not put it in. I am merely stating an observation that you can test. I do not know why it does not work.

Comment: That's why I'm asking, see my profile, and I'd like to know what value you gave to `LabelStyle`.

Comment: I apologise if  you interpreted my reply as disrespectful. I am a novice. When I placed LabelStyle in the position after Contours it was highlighted Red. I ran the code anyway using {FontSize->20}. The error message related to option LabelStyle not recognized. I checked for package dependencies and there seemed to be none. However, I am extremely happy to learn.

Comment: So, are you saying that I can manipulate the tick labelling for the legend bar?

Comment: @CerenBurcak you can choose the contours/splits in the bar. Not all the splits are labelled with a tick. If you run the manipulate and step through the tabs I just chose some examples to try. You can modify/add/change the list of contours. It may not be what you wanted.