# Customizing DensityPlot[]'s automatic bar legend

Tags: plotting, legending

To get the density plot of a function `f[x,y]` with a bar legend, I'm using

```
DensityPlot[f[x,y],{x,0,2 π},{y,0,2 π},PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I'm using `LinTicks[]` of `SciDraw` to have the axes ticks in units of pi. I would also like to customize the ticks in the bar legend to change in units of pi. There are some questions ([29643](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29643/changing-the-tick-labels-in-a-barlegend), [55150](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55150/barlegend-changes-in-version-10?rq=1)) here that are trying to solve this problem, but in order to use `BarLegend[]` one needs to know the range of the function being plotted. For the function I'm plotting, the range is not easy to get analytically. Using a somewhat brute-force approach, I can sample `f[x,y]` and get the min/max to use with `BarLegend[]`, but I'm looking for a more elegant approach to this. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use a pure function to specify the ticks of a `BarLegend`.

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[1 + x] + 2 Sin[y] + x

DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
                          Ticks -> (FindDivisions[{#1, #2, π}, Ceiling[(#2 - #1)/π]] &)]]
```

[image: Out]

Comment: I'm hoping WRI officially adds`Tick` support for `BarLegend` in 11. (+1).

Comment: Alternative with minor ticks: `Ticks -> ({Range[##, Pi], {Range[##, Pi/4]}} & @@ Round[{#1, #2}, Pi] &)`

Comment: The syntax highlighter on 11.3 picks up the `Ticks`  as a mistake, albeit it works as intended. Is there a different recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) to [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) the sample points that [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) uses.  Then apply your function to these to get the actual [`MinMax`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html) in the plot. A custom [`BarLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) can be constructed using [`FindDivisions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) and the undocumented `` Charting`Ticks `` option.

```
f[x_, y_] = Sin[1 + x] + 2 Sin[y] + x

Module[{dp, eval, range, divs},
 {dp, {eval}} = 
  Reap[DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[f[x, y]]]];

 range = MinMax[eval];

divs = FindDivisions[{Sequence @@ range, {π, π/4}}, {6, 4}]; 
divs = Join[divs[[1]], {#, ""} & /@ Complement[Flatten@divs[[2]], divs[[1]]]];

 Legended[dp,
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", range}, Charting`Ticks ->divs]]
 ]
```

[image]

The downside to this is that the function is evaluated twice at each sample point in `DensityPlot` which could be an issue depending on how expensive it is to evaluate.

Hope this helps.

## Update

borrowing from @Karsten7. `Ticks` function syntax. This is much better as you don't have to evaluate twice for each point.

```
myTicks[min_, max_, multiples_, subdivisions_] :=
 Module[{ticks},
  ticks = FindDivisions[{min, max, multiples}, subdivisions];
  ticks = Join[ticks[[1]], {#, ""} & /@ Complement[Flatten@ticks[[2]], ticks[[1]]]]
  ]

DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
   Ticks -> (myTicks[#1, #2, {π, π/4}, {6, 4}] &)]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like your use of `FindDivisions` to generate major and minor ticks, but the whole `Join` part is unnecessary. The output of `FindDivisions` already has the right format {list of major ticks, {list of minor ticks}} and the overlap of minor and major ticks is not a problem. See for example the major & minor ticks alternative I added as a comment to my answer. I think `subdivisions` should be computed automatically or an optional parameter. (+1)

Comment: @Karsten7. Oh, I didn't realise that. So I can just use `Ticks -> (FindDivisions[{#1, #2, {π, π/4}}, {6, 4}] &)`. Very nice!

Comment: @Karsten7. Where did you discover the minor-major ticks syntax?  I looked at [`Ticks` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) but did not notice it.  Is it an undocumented feature or a documentation bug for `Ticks`.