# Continuous gradient bar legend from RGBColor with user-defined ticks

Tags: color, legending, ticks

I am trying to adapt this [this question to change the ticks on a BarLegend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29643/34694) so have a user-defined continuous BarLegend with ticks

This code allows me to define the ticks I want (sort of, how many compartments I choose does affect things)

```
BarLegend[{{RGBColor[1, 1, 1], RGBColor[0.3, 0.5, 0.9]}, {0, 1}}, 9, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row", Ticks -> Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.2}]]
```

but I need a continuous gradient, which can be achieved by choosing a high number of compartments, but then the tick labels disappear

```
BarLegend[{{RGBColor[1, 1, 1], RGBColor[0.3, 0.5, 0.9]}, {0, 1}}, 200, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row", Ticks -> Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.2}]]
```

I will not always have just 2 stops in the gradient.

I also tried to convert a LinearGradientImage into a BarLegend, but was not successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the second argument to get a continuous gradient:

```
BarLegend[{{RGBColor[1, 1, 1], RGBColor[0.3, 0.5, 0.9]}, {0, 1}}, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row", Ticks -> Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.2}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***"convert a LinearGradientImage into a BarLegend"***

```
Show[LinearGradientImage[{White, RGBColor[0.3, 0.5, 0.9]}, {500, 40}], 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 500}, {0, 1}], None}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Full, LabelStyle -> 16, ImageSize -> 1 -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I’m confused as to what is the difference between this and OP’s code, can you please clarify this?

Comment: @CATrevillian, just removed the second argument in OP's code.